# How to get the instance created in the viewset, then return it in the response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class SolicitudCrear(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Grado.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GradoSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SolicitudCrear, self).create(request, args, kwargs)
        data = ?
        return Response({"data": data})
```

Comment: The default response for `CreateAPIView.create` is the created object serialized. If you're not doing anything in your `create` method you can just delete it

Comment: You can pull the data from database by using the *Primary Key*, which can possibly be  found in the serializer response.

Comment: I actually use the create method to apply logic before saving, but don't put it in the example, so I need it

Comment: What do you exactly wish to do? I think  better  explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following -

```
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(SolicitudCrear, self).create(request, args, kwargs)
        return response
```

Comment: this works, but to have the response.data instances